# Public issues in JIRA

Tags: jira

Is there a way to make issues publicly viewable in JIRA for a particular project?
By public I mean that it is not required to login to view them.
All other projects should stay private.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a specific permission scheme for your 'public project'
Grant anyone browse rights 
[image: Choose group 'Anyone']

Associate the new or modified permission scheme to the project(s) you want to open up.
That's it.

Francis

Comment: took a while to find, but the screen to edit permission schemes on Jira  7.1.9 is under Administration --> Issues --> Permission Schemes

Comment: Right - thanks for highlighting.
Something which works marvelously is the 'gg' shortcut.  Enter it on any jira / confluence screen (when not in a form field such as a text box).  A dialog box will popup where you can enter 'Permission Scheme' which provides a shortcut to the corresponding admin function.