# JIRA Integration

Tags: jira

What are the authentication schemes available for integrating a third-party application with jira 4.3. Obviously, getting username and password from customer sounds absurd. Also, i get that oauth authentication is available only from version 5. Please let me know. Thanks.

PS. I'm not looking for developing a plugin or using rest version5. I'm just trying to pull data from jira using rest api version 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just use one login (e.g. anonymous user) for connection with Jira behind the scenes without asking a user for a password.
You can also [allow user to create issues anonymously](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Allowing+users+to+create+issues+anonymously).
Or setup projects for [public browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5394533/941776).

Answer (score 0):

If it is local Jira(Installed on your system) you may call any Client API to pull data, by just providing url and encoded auth(with user name and password).

```
    String getUrl = applicationProperties.getjURL() + "/rest/api/1.0/XXX";
String jiraUser = applicationProperties.getJiraUser().trim();
String jiraPwd = applicationProperties.getJiraPassword().trim();
String auth = new String(Base64.encode(jiraUser + ":" + jiraPwd));

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getUrl);
StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(descrptionBean));
            post.setEntity(postingString);
            post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpClient httpClient = new org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
```

...
but if it is SSL/https secure then you need to set system property with truststore, keystore, keyStorePassword, etc  (in case if using Java as technology). You can use API JiraRestClientFactory to create a jira client as below.

```
public JiraRestClient getRestClient() {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", Constants.KEYSTORE);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", Constants.KEYSTORE);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
    String trustStore = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
    System.setProperty("-Dlog4j.configuration", "log4j.properties");
    if (trustStore == null) {
        Constants.REPORT.info("javax.net.ssl.trustStore is not defined, Please generate \"KeyStore.jks\" of JIRA Instance");
    }
    final JiraRestClientFactory jiraRestClientFactory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
    final HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();
    options.setConnectionTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    options.setSocketTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    options.setConnectionPoolTimeToLive(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    options.setRequestPreparer(new Effect<Request>() {

        @Override
        public void apply(final Request request) {

            new BasicHttpAuthenticationHandler(applicationProperties.getJiraUser().trim(), applicationProperties.getJiraPassword().trim()).configure(request);
        }
    });
    try {
        URI serverUri = new URI(applicationProperties.getjURL().trim());
        defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient<>(new NoOpEventPublisher(), new RestClientApplicationProperties(serverUri), ThreadLocalContextManagers.noop(), options);
        return jiraRestClientFactory.create(serverUri, defaultHttpClient);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = "Terminating the application while connecting to RestClient : " + e.getMessage();
        Constants.REPORT.info("javax.net.ssl.trustStore is not defined, Please generate \"KeyStore.jks\" of JIRA Instance");
        Constants.REPORT.info(msg);
        Constants.ERROR.info(msg);
        Constants.ERROR.info(Level.SEVERE, e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return null;
}
```